# Unable to start C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe when launching Console2

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, console, console2

I've just downloaded [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) as an alternative to the default cmd console that comes with windows, when I double click I get this error :

[image]

I added the C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe to the PATH environment variable, but it didn't fix it, what should I do ??

Comment: Are you running as Administrator? If not, try that

Comment: I run the app as an Administrator and I still get the same problem !

Comment: No idea then, sorry.

Comment: That error message looks bizarre. Why is there a semicolon at the end? It appears to me that it's trying to open cmd.exe; and that will never work. Try re downloading and re-installing. You may have a corrupt download?

Comment: @NateBergeron I couldn't obtain a installer, can you give me a link to that please ?

Comment: It's not an installer, just an application, same as in your picture. http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/files/latest/download

Comment: Give a try to ConEmu.

Comment: Your screen shot is not clear. Are you double clicking on the line labelled **Application** or the line **XML File**?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add cmd.exe to your path it will already be there.

Comment: It runs here, but I had to allow it some permissions in Avast. Perhaps your anti-virus is blocking it?

Answer (score 2):

Try going to `%APPDATA%\Console\console.xml` and removing the Console2 `<console shell="">` attribute.

Source: https://thecustomizewindows.com/2012/10/console2-error-fix-unable-to-start-console2/

Comment: is it possible you mean %APPDATA% ?

Comment: :-) nice first answer.